# Grails controller should implement all urlmappings?

Tags: grails, controller, http-status-code-404, url-mapping

I have my url mappings configured like this:

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {

    "/"(controller:"index")
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "500"(view:'/error')
    ////////////////////////

    "/recetas"(resources:"receta",version:'1.0',namespace:'user'){
        "/eventos"(resources:'evento',version:"1.0",namespace:"user")
    }

}
```

}

This url mapping generates this url-mapping-report.

```
|URL Mappings Configured for Application
|---------------------------------------
Dynamic Mappings
 |    *     | /${controller}/${action}?/${id}?(.${format)?              | Action: (default     action) |
 |    *     | ERROR: 500                                                | View:   /error             |
Controller: dbdoc
 |    *     | /dbdoc/${section}?/${filename}?/${table}?/${column}?      | Action: (default action) |
Controller: evento
 |   GET    | /recetas/${recetaId}/eventos                              | Action: index              |
 |   GET    | /recetas/${recetaId}/eventos/create                       | Action: create              |
 |   POST   | /recetas/${recetaId}/eventos                              | Action: save             |
 |   GET    | /recetas/${recetaId}/eventos/${id}                        | Action: show             |
 |   GET    | /recetas/${recetaId}/eventos/${id}/edit                   | Action: edit             |
 |   PUT    | /recetas/${recetaId}/eventos/${id}                        | Action: update           |
 |  DELETE  | /recetas/${recetaId}/eventos/${id}                        | Action: delete               |
Controller: index
 |    *     | /                                                         | Action: (default  action) |
Controller: receta
 |   GET    | /recetas                                                  | Action: index            |
 |   GET    | /recetas/create                                           | Action: create           |
 |   POST   | /recetas                                                  | Action: save             |
 |   GET    | /recetas/${id}                                            | Action: show             |
 |   GET    | /recetas/${id}/edit                                       | Action: edit             |
 |   PUT    | /recetas/${id}                                            | Action: update           |
 |  DELETE  | /recetas/${id}                                            | Action: delete           |
```

And my EventoController

```
package com.ar.dasding

import grails.converters.JSON;
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured;
import grails.transaction.Transactional;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Secured(["ROLE_ADMIN"])
class EventoController {

def index(Integer max) {

    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)

    def receta = Receta.get(params.recetaID)

    log.debug("Eventos para receta " + params.recetaID + ": " + receta.eventos)

    render receta.eventos as JSON
}

}
```

The recetaController is working correctly, but making this request to EventoController return 404

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/DasDingProject/recetas/1/eventos
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=30283EAC18BD88238A12449E825D8127; grails_remember_me=bWU6MTM5MTA4OTY5Njk3MTpmNmM3N2Q5MWU3ZTU3ZGE0OGRhZjAzNDViYzU5NDg3Yg
Host:localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/DasDingProject/userHome
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1015
Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 14:04:04 GMT
```

Is it possible that the problem is the controller is not implementing all actions mapped in url mappings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know what is going wrong, the definition of the namespaces is making the routing of the controllers not working. I couldn´t get the namespaces to work, but taking them out made the routing work.

Comment: the order of the urlmappings also matters - your resources should be above the catchall $controller/$action mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that there's something strange going on with the specificity of the url mappings.

What happens if you replace your "/eventos" mapping with:

"/recetas/${recetaID}/eventos"(controller:"eventos",action:"index")

on its own, outside the 'recetas' mapping closure

Comment: I added what you told me, and broke recetas mapping too